Getting the titlebar color and text color of a themed Delphi form
I have a Delphi 12 themed application.  Theme is selected under options to (for example) "Iceberg CLassico".
At runtime I would like to query what the themed UI titlebar color and titlebar text are set to.
How can I do this?
Why I want this is I am creating forms with a customtitlebar (for extra buttons in the titlebar area) at runtime.  When a form gets the customtitlebar built and displayed at runtime it ignores the main form style.  The rest of the dialog is styled OK, just not my custom titlebar area.  So I want to set the background and text colors manually using
fname.customtitlebar.BackgroundColor:=Whatever;
fname.customtitlebar.InactiveBackgroundColor:=Whatever;

If I specify say clgreen and clyellow then I get yellow text on a green background, so that code is right, just the color detection is wrong.  I have tried to query the main form colors with
fname.customtitlebar.BackgroundColor:=StyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetSystemColor(clActiveCaption);
fname.customtitlebar.InactiveBackgroundColor:=StyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetSystemColor(clActiveCaption);

and
fname.customtitlebar.BackgroundColor:=form1.customtitlebar.BackgroundColor;
fname.customtitlebar.InactiveBackgroundColor:=form1.customtitlebar.InactiveBackgroundColor;

but they do not give the correct colors.
Any ideas on how to extract the correct current themed titlebar background and titlebar text colors?

Colors in Delphi are represented by the TColorRec record.  The system colors are determined by $FF000000 or (bitwise) 0-30.  Normal colors would be from $00000000 to $00FFFFFF.  When the system colors are sent down to the API doing the painting, it sets the color based on the system colors if it needs to.
I'm sure there is a way to get the correct color via an API call, but the easiest is probably to just paint a pixel in a bitmap (or a canvas if you already have one).
var ActualColor: TColor;
  var ABitmap := TBitmap.Create(1,1);
  try
    ABitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0,0] := clHighlight;
    ActualColor := ABitmap.Canvas.Pixels[0,0];
  finally
    ABitmap.Free;
  end;

Not quite the "best" way, but it should work fine.
